# Brownish marks on upper surface of chilli leaves gradually forming lesions

Tags: identification, leaves, diseases, chili

I have a young ghost chilli growing in a pot outside which is displaying browning on the upper surface (but not on the lower surface) of its leaves, primarily along the veins at the base of the plant. I first noticed this about a week ago, and by now it has begun progressing to forming lesions.

Here is the plant as I first noticed it, from 7 Nov:
[image]
[image]

Here is the leaf from the first photo yesterday (11 Nov):
[image]
[image]
And the plant as it is now:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've also noticed lesions forming on several of my other plants, but they don't seem to share the same initial form of a large surface-level brown/green blotch so I wouldn't be surprised if they're from an entirely different cause.

From a slightly older Hungarian wax:
[image]
[image]
[image]

And a cayenne (although I've seen this on a few of my other chilli plants):
[image]
[image]
[image]

All of these plants are growing outside in 8-15L pots in a fruit and vege soil mix from a local nursery.

Does anyone have any idea what the cause (causes?) of this might be? I wondered about nutrient toxicity due to overfeeding but it's much harder to find information about symptoms of toxicity than deficiency. We have also had on-and-off trouble with aphids, but this seems to be primarily on older leaves which have, to my knowledge, not been touched much by them.